# pip, don't fail when one of the extra index urls fail

Tags: python, pip

I have a private pypi repo on my local network, where I keep my private Python packages. I configured pip with following configuration file, so that it is able to download my private packages as well as pypi.python.org packages *when I am connected to my local network*:

```
[global]
index-url = https://pypi.python.org/simple
trusted-host = pypi.python.org
               192.168.2.1
extra-index-url= http://192.168.2.1:8080/simple
```

But if I go outside my local network, I can't use pip even for packages on pypi.python.org because it fails to connect to my local pypi server. I want it to behave like this:

- If you find the package in any one of the index urls inside configuration file, then don't fail, just download the package you have found.

Is this possible?